# Stanford NLP Output Formatting

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp

Using the Stanford NLP, I want my text to go through lemmatization and coreference resolution.

So for an input.txt:     "Stanford is located in California.  It is a great University, founded in 1891."
I would want the output.txt:      "Stanford be located in California. Stanford be a great University, found in 1891."

I am also looking to get a table where the first column consists of the name-entities that were recognized in the text, and the second column is the name class they were identified as. Thus, for the example sentence above, it would be something like:

1st Column                    2nd Column
Stanford                      Location, Organization
California                    Location

Thus, in the table, the name-entities would occur only once.

There's nothing I was able to find online about manipulating the default xml output or making direct changes to the input text file using the NLP.  Could you give me any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: It would be really helpful for you to flag this with the Java tag as well, in order to attract more people to your question.  You should also read this guide as the way your Question is phrased it is nearly asking the community to write the code for you (which is not what SO is about) https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the command line you can use `-outputFormat text` to get a human readable version or `-outputFormat json` to get a `json` version.  In Java code you can use `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.prettyPrint()` or `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.jsonPrint()` to print out an Annotation.